# How to sort from for each in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, sorting, for-loop, each

From an array I start for each entry a function with a argument from the array (its friends from facebook). The function returns either 0 or a number bigger than 0. So at the moment, it justs displays it all mixed up, but I want it to show first all entries which get the result bigger than 0 from the function and then all, which are 0. I've no idea, how to do this.

This is my current code.

```
foreach ($friends as $key=>$value) {
//removed unimportant things
                    $friendresult = friendscore($id = $fvalue[id]);

             if ($friendresult == "0") {

        echo '<li>';
            echo '<a class="box" href="javascript:invite('. $fvalue[id] . ')">';
                echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fvalue[id] . '/picture" title="' . $fvalue[name] . '" />';
                echo '<label>' . $fvalue[name] . '</label>';
                echo '<b>Invite</b>';
            echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
            }

            if ($friendresult !=="0"){

             echo '<li>';
            echo '<a class="box">';
                echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fvalue[id] . '/picture" title="' . $fvalue[name] . '" />';
                echo '<label>' . $fvalue[name] . '</label>';
                echo '<div class="totaltext">Score:'.$friendresult. '</div>';
            echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>'; 

            }}
```

Edit: Found solution. Sometimes its too simple.

```
if ($friendresult == "0") {

            $friend.= '<li>';
            $friend.= '<a class="box" href="javascript:invite('. $fvalue[id] . ')">';
            $friend.= '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fvalue[id] . '/picture" title="' . $fvalue[name] . '" />';
            $friend.= '<label>' . $fvalue[name] . '</label>';
            $friend.= '<b>Invite</b>';
            $friend.= '</a>';
            $friend.= '</li>';
            }

            if ($friendresult !="0"){

             $nofriend.= '<li>';
            $nofriend.= '<a class="box">';
            $nofriend.= '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fvalue[id] . '/picture" title="' . $fvalue[name] . '" />';
            $nofriend.= '<label>' . $fvalue[name] . '</label>';
            $nofriend.= '<div class="totaltext">Score:'.$friendresult. '</div>';
            $nofriend.= '</a>';
            $nofriend.= '</li>'; 

            }
```

echo $friend.$nofriend;

Comment: where is $fvalue defined? Should the foreach reference $fvalue instead of $value?

Comment: Are you sure `!==` is not supposed to be `!=`? These are not the same if you didn't know

Comment: The code works fine, but I just want to sort it. So maybe after the question, add it to an array? And the !== and != is just that, !== also returns false if they are not from the same type, right?